# query_post while (have post) get_template_part()?

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, templates, get-template-part

My goal: Is to give the user the ability, if they so choose, to create a new category.

I have the current categories saved in a separate php file and call them in using `get_template_part()`, there are currently 4 categories.

If the user wants to create a 5th category, I want them to be able to choose the name and then create it using the same template as the previous categories.

Example Template.

```
<section> 
<h1>Main</h1>
<article>something</article>
<div>box</div><div>box</div>box<div>box</div>
</section>
```

This should then appear on the home page along with the other 4 categories.

Comment: I believe you have fundamentally misunderstood what Custom Post Types are and how they work. Or I am misunderstanding you. Or both (likely this). Can you describe what it is you want to achieve without the use of technical terms (which you might possibly be interpreting incorrectly)?

Comment: @JohannesPille Sure, I want to enable the user to create a new category, each category has a default html/css/php structure, once this category has been created, it should be visible on the home page.

Comment: @JohannesPille Perhaps, I want to create a new "page" but I want this page to appear on the home page? There's clearly something that has gone over my head whilst looking at the codex.

Comment: 1. Questions are [editable](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/108314/edit) - instead of using the comments for clarification, improve your question. 2. Almost everything, that can be done with code can be done in a variety of ways. You are mixing *approaches* whilst it is unclear what the *outcome* you are pursuing is. 3. No one, here nor elsewhere, will write your entire code for you. *But*, it is apparent that you have researched and tried before asking, hence that prerequisite has been fullfilled. --> Follow my first comment and edit your question thoroughly.

Comment: @JohannesPille sure, I've just edited it now. It seems to me this a common cms practice. I believe it's somewhere a along the lines of creating new a page, which uses some template, then that template appears on the home page.

Comment: So yea after some playing around it was pretty simple, I just created a custom post type, created a loop that called in that post type, and then used   `get_template_part()`.

    `<?php 
    query_posts(array('post_type' => 'category'));
    if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    
     echo get_template_part( 'template','index' ); ?>
    
    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>`

Meh... I'll post it as an answer when I'm allowed to.